How to organize items on css grid with an uneven number of items in each column
I want to organize items top to bottom on a css grid with each column containing any number of items, but when I try to put elements on the next column they don't start at the top of the grid, instead they stay on the same row as the previous item. How can I fix that?


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns with equal width */
  gap: 10px; /* Space between grid items */
}

.column-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.column-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.column-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item column-1">Item 1.1</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-1">Item 1.2</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-1">Item 1.3</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.1</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.2<br>foo</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.3<br>foo</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.4</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.5</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-3">Item 3.1</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-3">Item 3.2</div>
  </div>




You are missing one property to tell grid that you want to actually fill the column. It's called grid-auto-flow
From mdn docs

The grid-auto-flow CSS property controls how the auto-placement
algorithm works, specifying exactly how auto-placed items get flowed
into the grid.
...
column
Items are placed by filling each column in turn, adding new columns as necessary.

So just add grid-auto-flow: column; property to .grid-container class.


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* SOLUTION */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns with equal width */
  gap: 10px; /* Space between grid items */
}

.column-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.column-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.column-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item column-1">Item 1.1</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-1">Item 1.2</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-1">Item 1.3</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.1</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.2<br>foo</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.3<br>foo</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.4</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-2">Item 2.5</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-3">Item 3.1</div>
    <div class="grid-item column-3">Item 3.2</div>
  </div>




If you’ve given a grid container columns, the CSS parser places children in writing direction sequence by default. So (assuming a LTR, top-to-bottom language like English) after your first .column-1 item, the next position it checks is the second column. But the second item also has .column-1, so it skips that space, repeating as often as needed until it hits a space that matches—which won’t happen until the next row.
That just happens to work for your use case, until you give it a .column-2 item. Then suddenly the next space it checks (same row, second column) is valid! But what you intended the CSS parser to do is use the first valid space in the container.
.grid-container {
    grid-auto-flow: dense;

    ...

